# Trying to get month & year from timestamp in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

```
$stfeeres = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student INNER JOIN stledger ON student.stid = stledger.stid WHERE student.status='Active' AND date('m-Y', strtotime(stledger.entrytime))=date('m-Y')");
```

I am trying get month and year. entrytime is timestamp in table.
Please help me.

I am getting error

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_array()/mysqli\_fetch\_assoc()/mysqli\_fetch\_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli\_result, boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysqli-fetch-array-mysqli-fetch-assoc-mysqli-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1)

Answer (score 0):

Try it so:

```
SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE MONTH(entrytime)=MONTH('2017-08-18') AND YEAR(entrytime)=YEAR('2017-08-18')
```

Than the mysql will look for the month "08" and the year "2017".

EDIT:

```
$yourDate='2017-08-18'; // or date('Y-m-d');

$stfeeres = mysql_query("SELECT `stledger`.entrytime FROM student INNER JOIN stledger ON student.stid = stledger.stid WHERE student.status='Active'
AND MONTH(stledger.entrytime)=MONTH({$yourDate})
AND YEAR(stledger.entrytime)=YEAR({$yourDate})");
```

And do not use `mysql_*` use instead `mysqli_*`.

Comment: It is not working. This entrydate is in another table. I added INNERJOIN to join 2 tables.

Comment: I add the full SQL.

Answer (score 0):

$m=date('m-Y');
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student INNER JOIN stledger ON student.stid = stledger.stid WHERE student.status='Active' AND DATE_FORMAT(stledger.entrydate, '%m-%Y')='$m'");

I got the result from this. :)